# How to find directories containing only files older than X days?

Tags: linux, shell-script, find

I need to delete directories that only contain files (created/modified) older than X days.

I tried this, but it will only show files from today and not recursively...

```
for d in *; do   
  find "$d" -mindepth 1 -mtime -180 -print -quit | | grep -q . ||     
  echo rm -rf "$d";
done
```

Comment: Firstly, `mtime` doesn't mean indicate the age of the files. It indicates the modification time. If that is actually what yo want, then you need `-mtime +180`. `mtime -180` means modified within the last 180 days. I would also recommend against using `*` because you could accidentally return data that you don't want. To make sure, simply use the parent directory as the argument.

Comment: What should happen to a directory that contains child directories? Presumably you don't want to delete it as the children in turn might contain files that are younger than your age limit

Comment: @NasirRiley If a file is created or modified does not really matter. I need to delete the directory if the content is older than x.

Answer (score 2):

You want "*to delete directories that only contain files older than X days*".

Here's one way of handling it:

- For each directory in turn, starting from leaf nodes:
- Count the number of its child directories; skip if non-zero
- Count the number of its non-directory items; skip if zero
- Count the number of its files matching your criterion (age)
- Delete the directory if the two file counts are the same

This solution requires GNU `find` or an alternate version that understands `-mindepth`, `-maxdepth`, and `printf`.

This particular example sets your `X` to `180` (days).

```
days=180
find ./* -depth -type d -exec sh -c '
    [ -z "'"$days"'" ] && exit 1
    printf "Considering directory: %s\n" "$1"

    dirs=$(find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | xargs)
    if [ -n "$dirs" ]
    then
        printf "Found child directories: (%s)\n" "$dirs"
        exit 0
    fi

    all=$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -printf x | wc -c)
    got=$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +'"$days"' -printf x | wc -c)
    printf "Found %d item(s) and matched %d\n" $all $got

    if [ $all -gt 0 ] && [ $all -eq $got ]
    then
        printf "Delete directory: %s\n" "$1"
        : rm -rf "$1"
    fi
' _ {} \;
```

The seemingly strange quoting around the two uses of the variable `$days` is to ensure that although the rest of the script is enclosed in single quotes, the variable is enclosed in double-quotes so that its value can be determined. It may be more easily understood as `'..start of script..' "$variable" '..remainder of script..'`, except that we have no spaces between the ending of one type of quotes and the start of the other.

Remove the `printf` statements if you want the code to run silently. Remove the colon (`:`) in front of the `rm -rf` when you are ready to execute the delete action.

Comment: shouldn't you put `-mtime +179` for 180 days and more? this way it'll be 181 days and more... reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days

Comment: @golder3 the question actually says "_older than X days_", so I'll adjust my `180` to be `X`

Comment: my point was that if you input 180 as X you actually get files older than 181 days

Comment: @golder3 `-mtime 180` will match files that were either modified precisely 181 days ago, or modified more than 181 days ago. That's what the OP asked for: "_files older than 180 days_".

Comment: Yes, and logically, if you don't round the number of days, a file 180 days and 2 hours old is more than 180 days old and it won't be deleted... But OK, just wanted to point that out to OP

Comment: @golder3 it's an interesting issue, but (as I suspect you know) it's down the integer size of the units being considered. Since we're in days, 180.9 days is still 180 days

Comment: The OP had `-mtime -180` and with POSIX compliant `find` implementations including GNU `find`, the opposite of is `-mtime +179` (or `'(' -mtime 180 -o -mtime +180 ')'`), not `-mtime +180`. So you'd need `-mtime +"$((days - 1))"` for files older than `$days` days, 180.9 days is more than 180 days with most people's definition of *more*.

Comment: You could make it `days=180 find` to avoid that funny quoting.

Comment: Note that while `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` are now widespread, AFAIK, `-printf` is still GNU-specific. Omitting the list of files `find` is to work on (here `.`) is also non-standard, non-portable.

Comment: The script considers directory files (`-type d`), regular files (`-type f`), but what about the other types of files (symlinks, devices, fifos etc)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm pretty sure they're covered (`$all` counts them), in that if they exist in the directory then the criterion "_only contain files […]_" cannot match `$got` counting just files

Comment: Ah sorry missed that, so you're skipping directories that contain non-directory non-regular files even if they're all old. I suppose that makes sense and makes it a fail-safe if files of those types are not expected.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the shallowest directories that don't contain (at any level) non-directory files not older than 180 days (if both `./a/b` and `./a` don't contain recent files, only report `./a` as `./a/b` is part of that), that would be a variation on [Listing only shallowest directories containing no files, all the way down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/433091), so you could use the same approach as [my answer](/a/685543) there if on a GNU system:

```
find . -type d -print0 -o -mtime -180 -printf 'f/%h\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zru |
  LC_ALL=C awk -F/ -v RS='\0' '
    function parent(path) {
      sub("/[^/]*$", "", path)
      return path
    }
    $1 == "f" {
      sep = path = ""
      for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        black[path = path sep $i]
        sep = FS
      }
      next
    }
    ! ($0 in black) && ($0 == "." || parent($0) in black)'
```

Where instead of painting black the directories that have *any* non-directory file, we paint black the ones that have *any non-directory file not older than 180 days*.

Or a variation which removes directories from an array when a recent file is found:

```
find . -type d -printf '%p/\0' -o -mtime -180 -printf '%h/f\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
  LC_ALL=C awk -F/ -v RS='\0' '
    function parent(path) {
      sub("[^/]+/?$", "", path)
      return path
    }
    /\/$/ {dir[$0]; next}
    {
      path = ""
      for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        delete dir[path = path $i FS]
    }
    END {
      for (path in dir) if (! (parent(path) in dir)) print path
    }'
```

If you want both `./a` and `./a/b` above (not only the shallowest), it becomes simpler:

```
find . -type d -printf '%p/\0' -o -mtime -180 -printf '%h/f\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
  LC_ALL=C awk -F/ -v RS='\0' '
    /\/$/ {dir[$0]; next}
    {
      path = ""
      for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        delete dir[path = path $i FS]
    }
    END {
      for (path in dir) print path
    }'
```

If you want to delete them, add a `-v ORS='\0'` to `awk` to print them NUL-delimited, and pipe to `xargs -r0 rm -rf`, but beware that if `./` is returned (if there's no recent file anywhere in the current directory), most `rm` implementations will refuse to do anything¹.

Since those approaches run `find` and traverse the whole directory tree only once, they're more efficient than more naive approaches that crawl the contents of each directory for recent files.

One such less efficient approach in `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND/^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/**/*(NDm-180Y1^/)'])
```

(won't include `.`, though you could add it to the list with `{.,**/*}(...)`)

If it's only the subdirectories of the current directory that you want to consider, then that approach becomes more efficient (as the `Y1` above stops at the first match) as well as being shorter/simpler:

```
print -rC1 -- *(ND/^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/**/*(NDm-180Y1^/)'])
```

---

<sup>¹ as a work around for the fact that the expansion of `.*` in some shells includes `.` and `..` and could be catastrophic with `rm -rf .*`. The `rm` builtin of `zsh` (a shell that doesn't have that misfeature), which you enable with `zmodload zsh/files`, will accept `rm -rf ./` and empty the current working directory.</sup>